# Whatsapp like profile picture animation

Tags: android, animation, whatsapp

I wanted to have picture animation just like whatsapp does on friend's profile picture. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this ?

**Edited**

I my case, the `imagview` is on top and below it, there is `listview`. when i scroll down the `listview`, the `imageview` should increase its size and when i scroll up, the `imageview` size should reduce its size. The maximum height of `imageview` can be 500 and minimum height of `imageview` can be 100. I have already achieve this. What i am doing is, changing the `imagview` height. But its not that much smooth.

Comment: I got it and added my answer please check and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 4):

Make a global method to show the image in full view in your `YourApplication.java`:

```
public static void showExpandableImage(Context context, String imageUri, String title, View view) {
        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", imageUri);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUri)) {
                imageUri = getURLForResource(R.drawable.user_placeholder); // default image in drawable
            }

            Pair<View, String> bodyPair = Pair.create(view, imageUri);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(((Activity)context), bodyPair);

            ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, options.toBundle());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public static String getURLForResource (int resourceId) {
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackage.name/" + resourceId).toString();
    }
```

Add this code in `image_view_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add this code in `ViewImageActivity`:

```
public class ViewImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView title;
    private String my_title, imgPath;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_view_layout);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        title = findViewById(R.id.title);

        imgPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("image");
        my_title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(my_title)) {
                title.setText(my_title);
            }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imgPath)) {

            ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageView, imgPath);
            Picasso.with(this).load(imgPath)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                        .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                        .into(imageView);

        } else {
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageView, "NotAvailable");
                Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                        .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                        .into(imageView);
            }

    }

}
```

Simply call this method where ever you want to show WhatsApp like animation:

An Example in Activity:

```
ImageView image_view = findViewById(R.id.pic_image_view);
showExpandableImage(MyActivity.this, "UrlOfImage", "MyTitle", image_view); // replace with your content
```

An example in Adapter:

```
ImageView image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic_image_view);
showExpandableImage(context, "UrlOfImage", "MyTitle", image_view); // replace with your content
```

Comment: The animation for going back is not smooth. How to achieve that? if we want smoother animations.

Comment: No idea on it, you can post a new question on that

Answer (score 2):

you have to Use Android Design Support Library and using that you can Achieve

Here is the Link :: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

in which you have to find **Collapsing Toolbars** using this control you can achieve this.

for more you can refer this Link :: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare
it will very helpful to you.

Comment: But image should not be fully invisible. and the image must be able to pull down to increase its size

Comment: Hey. I'm looking for the same.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: For iOS, https://github.com/MaitrayeeGhosh/ParallaxScrollingAnimationEffectTutorial

Comment: @spaceMonkey I got it and added my answer above please check and let me know if you have any issues.